# JQuery invoking Spring Rest service: Cross-Origin issue vs ParseError

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to invoke a REST service with jquery, but either I get a Cross Origin Problem (when I do not specify the datatype in jquery invocation) or a parseerror (when I do).

JQuery use:

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/Project/api/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success: function(json) { 
            console.log("OK");
            console.log(json);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log("NO");
          console.log("STATUS:" + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Server side, I am using Spring REST this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Entity> getEntities() {
    List<Entity> found = controller.findEntities();

    return found;
}
```

The serialized data are correct, as invoking the REST API in the browser produces correct JSON.

I also added the following CORS filter, which **does NOT seem to be executed**, as "AA" is not printed:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("AA");

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.lh.xxx.web.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was strictly related to the filter not being executed: [Spring Filter not getting invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762216/spring-filter-not-getting-invoked)

When executing the filter, correct json is returned to the invoking client.