# How to catch a Thymeleaf (view) rendering exception with Spring?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

So far now, I've tried;

**1)** to create a bean which extends org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver and implement doResolveException(..) method (It was waste of time because it already returns ModelAndView). The code is below:

```
 @Override
protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
    response.setStatus(534);
    log.trace("exception from HandlerExceptionResolver");
    log.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);

    Client bugsnag = new Client(BUGSNAG_API_KEY);

    //bugsnag code omitted

    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("error");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**2)** to create a bean which implements javax.servlet.Fiter and implement doFilter(..) method (It was waste of time, too. Because it already returns ModelAndView)

```
 @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        errorHandler.handleError(ex);
        log.trace("exception from HandlerExceptionResolver");
        log.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);

        Client bugsnag = new Client(BUGSNAG_API_KEY);

        //bugsnag code omitted

        RequestDispatcher error = request.getRequestDispatcher("error");
        error.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

**3)** and the @ControllerAdvice annotation (this works all other exception except view exceptions like parsing)

All 3 solutions didn't work for me to catch view exception and navigate to error page. I think there must be a solution in filter level. But i couldn't manage it. (That's why methods return ModelAndView object does not work)

Any suggestion?

Comment: `@ControllerAdvice` annotation cannot work, because you can only use it for exception **inside** a controller, and here you want to process exception in a **view**. I'm unsure for `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver`, but doc states *Spring HandlerExceptionResolver implementations deal with unexpected exceptions that occur **during controller execution**.* But Filter method **should** work. Could you elaborate on you problems with it ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta actually, i think the filter solution should work, too. I defined my filter with mappings in web.xml, created a  bean, but nothing happens (doesn't navigate my error pages or logs the exception manually). also there is a thymeleaf log like --> ErrorHandler.fatalError:57 qtp1732250066-18 [THYMELEAF][qtp1732250066-18] Fatal error during parsing.

Comment: Are you sure your filter is correctly initialized and called ? You say it is a bean, but it should either be a plain filter (outside Spring), or you should use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` (cf : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28763222/3545273)

Comment: @SergeBallesta here is my web.xml  filter
  <filter>
        <filter-name>errorHandlerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>errorHandlerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: `targetFilterLifecycle=true` is seldom useful for a `DelegatingFilterProxy`. But is the bean **name** really `errorHandlerFilter` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes Serge, it is : 
 <bean class="....advices.ErrorHandlerFilter" name="errorHandlerFilter"/>. Otherwise there would be exception like NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, right?

Comment: You should add a log at the begining of the `doFilter` method, and another one after the `filterChain.doFilter(...);` statement, just to control whether the exception has bean *eaten* by something else ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks, your solution worked. The problem was that in project we use grunt. grunt web.xml file was overriding webinf/web.xml. If you write your answer i can approve it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ControllerAdvice` annotation cannot work, because you can only use it for exception inside a controller, and here you want to process exception in a view. I'm unsure for `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver`, but doc states Spring `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementations deal with unexpected exceptions that occur during controller execution. But Filter method should work.

To be sure of what really happens, you should add a log at the begining of the `doFilter` method, and another one after the `filterChain.doFilter(...);` statement, just to control whether the exception has bean eaten by something else, or if the problem lies in filter declaration.

Answer (score 0):

A further approach is to create a controller method with `@RequestMapping(value="/error")`, but I don't know what for information you will get in the method.
Furthermore you can have a look at [How to handle exceptions thrown while rendering a view in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245932/how-to-handle-exceptions-thrown-while-rendering-a-view-in-spring-mvc)